# Intercompatibility of aes gcm encryption and decryption

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, mismatch

Please share working code of encryption in node js and decryption in java AES/GCM/NoPadding

In **Node js**:

```js
function createCipherCommon(text, alg, key, iv) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(alg, key, iv);
    cipher.setAAD(Buffer.from("aad", 'utf8'));
    return {
        enc: cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64'),
        tag: cipher.getAuthTag().toString('base64')
    };
}
```

In **Java**, the below code is giving javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!

```java
public static String createDecipherCommon(byte[] text, byte[] key, String iv, String tag) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException, DecoderException {
        byte[] ivBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv.getBytes());
        byte[] tagBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(tag.getBytes());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), new GCMParameterSpec(128, ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.length));
        cipher.updateAAD("aad".getBytes());
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(text, 0, text.length));
    }
```

Comment: Working fine. The difference is that in java the authentication tag should be appended at the end of the encrypted text. But in node js its not required. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Node js**, I made these changes and now it is working fine:

```js
function createCipherCommon(text, alg, key, iv) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(alg, key, iv);
    cipher.setAAD(Buffer.from("aad", 'utf8'));
    return {
        encwithtag: Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text, 'utf8'), cipher.final(), cipher.getAuthTag()]).toString('base64')
    };
}
```

In **Java**, unaltered

```java
public static String createDecipherCommon(byte[] text, byte[] key, String iv, String tag) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException, DecoderException {
        byte[] ivBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv.getBytes());
        byte[] tagBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(tag.getBytes());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), new GCMParameterSpec(128, ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.length));
        cipher.updateAAD("aad".getBytes());
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(text, 0, text.length));
    }
```